# Is there a way for user to globally override the default value of a keyword argument for all functions that use it?

Tags: python, pandas

While using pandas, I find myself specifying inplace=True in many function calls. I use that much more than the default value, which tends to be inplace=False wherever it is defined, by convention.

Is there a way to specify some (perhaps global) variable like

```
inplace = True
```

and then do something that will cause that variable to be automatically passed to any pandas function that has an 'inplace' keyword argument, eliminating the need to type it every time?

Concretely, an ideal solution would make

```
df.set_index(['id', 'year'])
```

equivalent to

```
df.set_index(['id', 'year'], inplace=True)
```

and similarly for any pandas function that takes an 'inplace' argument.

This seems like a general Python question--but my current context is pandas. I did not find any other questions on the topic of user override of default argument values (except by defining some kind of wrapper function, which would involve a similar amount of typing to invoke). As far as trying something goes, I have no leads. I already know that just defining a variable with that name in the calling scope will not assign the value to an argument within the scope of a function.

I'm using Python 3.7.6 and pandas 0.25.3, in case that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two years later, I would suggest solving this problem by just storing frequently used `kwargs` in a dictionary and unpacking:

```
kws = {'inplace': True}
df.set_index(['id', 'year'], **kws)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve such behavior is to monkey-patch the code you want to change - e.g. if you want to change behavior of pd.DataFrame you can do that (there are some minor drawbacks here like giving up using `inplace` as positional argument if it ever was + maybe someone could point more issues, but overall it works):

```
import pandas as pd
import inspect
import functools
for m in inspect.getmembers(pd.DataFrame, predicate=inspect.isfunction):
    if 'inplace' in inspect.getfullargspec(m[1]).args:
        setattr(pd.DataFrame, m[0], functools.partialmethod(m[1], inplace=True))
```

With that you can still call `df.dropna(inplace=False)`, but default will be `inplace=True`.

That said I would very strongly discourage you from doing so - such changes make it really difficult for someone else to read random part of your code: they are likely to not know that you did such replacement and your code might make no sense to them.

Answer (score 1):

Try [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) `partial`

```py
from functools import partial
f = partial(DataFrame.set_index, inplace=True)
f(df) # should be roughly equivalent to df.det_index(in_place=True)
```